# Error in saving manipulated dicom to a new readable dicom file?

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom

I have a 2D DICOM image with 12 bits, I need to do some modification on Bits-Store to convert it to 8 bits. For this aim, I modify the pixel_array. To save this new modified pixel_array as a DICOM image I need the same meta_data of the original image such that the resulted DICOM is completely readable.
I did the following but the final DICOM is not readable. Can anyone help me?
'''

```
import pydicom


ds = pydicom.dcmread('dicom_12bit.dcm')
high = 255
low = 0 
cmin = ds.pixel_array.min()
cmax = ds.pixel_array.max()
cscale = cmax - cmin
scale = float(high - low) / cscale
dcm_ds.pixel_array = (dcm_ds.pixel_array - cmin) * scale + low
dcm_ds.pixel_array = (dcm_ds.pixel_array.clip(low, high) + 0.5).astype(np.uint8)
dcm_ds.PixelData = dcm_ds.pixel_array.tobytes()
dcm_ds.save_as("new_8bit_dicom.dcm")
```

the bits stored should be now 8 bits in the new DICOM file. But it is not saved correctly.

Comment: Do you have an example (patient deidentified, of course) `.dcm` file that we can test out?

Comment: how is it not readable? you get an error from a dicom viewer? or maybe pydicom itself?

Comment: Actually the DICOM image is duplicated when I visualize it with some DICOM viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The viewed image looks weird because its still being treated as 12-bit data in a 16-bit container. You need to set *Bits Stored*, *Bits Allocated* and *High Bit* to match the new bit depth:

```py
dcm_ds.BitsStored = 8
dcm_ds.BitsAllocated = 8
dcm_ds.HighBit = 7
```

If you've gone from signed to unsigned you also need to change *Pixel Representation* to 0.